# MapBox: Getting lattitude() and longitude() on LocationComponent

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I have trouble using locationComponent() for getting latitude() and longitude() of device location. I'm migrating from an older version of the MapBox SDK to the latest, which is 7.0.1

I've tried searching for answers around, but still it does not give me exactly what needs to be done.

Here's my code:

```
 private void enableLocationComponent() {
    locationEngine = new LocationEngineProvider(this).obtainLocationEngineBy(LocationEngine.Type.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    locationEngine.setInterval(1000);//this is means get location every 1 second
    locationEngine.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationEngine.setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);

    // Check if permissions are enabled and if not request
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {

        // Get an instance of the component
        LocationComponent locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
        locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation();

        // Activate
        locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(this,mapboxMap.getStyle());

        // Enable to make component visible
        locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);

        // Set the component's camera mode
        locationComponent.setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING);

        // Set the component's render mode
        locationComponent.setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
    }
}
```

I hope a solution to the question will be given or tell me what I missed, and explained briefly. Thanks!

Dependencies:

```
 // Mapbox Maps SDK dependency
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.0.1'

// Mapbox Services SDK dependency to retrieve direction routes
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:4.3.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:4.3.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
locationEngine.getLastLocation(new LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
    Location location = result.getLastLocation();
    if (location != null) {
      // process last location
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // failure
  }
});
```

Above is an asynchronous call that will return the last known device's location.

On the other hand, the

```
locationComponent.getLastKnownLocation();
```

will return the last known/displayed location on the map by the component, which will always be `null` in your case because you've not activated or enabled the component yet.

After the component is activated, enabled and visible for the first time, it will make the same asynchronous call to establish the current location. Afterward, you can rely on the component's last known location in most foreground cases, but to find out the initial user's location, you should definitely use the `LocationEngine`.

Comment: I'll look on to this, your explanation clears the confusion I have. Thanks

Comment: Hi my app crashes when adding the code you've mentioned above

Comment: What's the exception @JoshuaMark?

Comment: In my tests it crashes too on:
locationEngine.getLastLocation(new LocationEngineCallback<LocationEngineResult>() {